# How to inherit a certain position (CSS)

Tags: html, css, frontend

After ~2 hours of researching I couldn't find a solution for my problem, I am trying to inherit the center of the background since the "blurred-box" gets bigger depending on the computer resolution.

It looks like this(laptop resolution):
[image: website image 1]
And I would like to make it show the center of the background image instead of the corner.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477346611705-65d1883cee1e?dpr=0.800000011920929&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=800&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.blurred-box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 550px;
  height: 670px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blurred-box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.user-login-box {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.user-login-box>* {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred-box">
  <div class="user-login-box">
    <h1>text here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

If someone posts a solution I would like to have a link for documentation with those informations(if that is okay), thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your issue is from the question as asked.  Could you include enough code to constitute a [mcve], and a clear explanation of the desired behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ?  Perhaps with images if they would help convey the needed information?

Comment: @AlexanderNied My bad, I will add more informations.

Comment: also please add more information of what you tryint to achieve. are you trying to center another element to the horizontal and vertical center of the box?

Comment: @tacoshy More information added.

Comment: So I understand you right, that you simply want to center the blurred box? Why not simply use `flexbox` + `justify-content: center; align-items: center;`? also you can cenetr images directly in css with `background-position`.

Comment: @tacoshy the blurred box is already centered, but the size changes with the computer resolution so it displays the corner of the background image(inherited) instead of the center.

Comment: I think tacoshy is suggesting you use [`background-position: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) to center the background-- does that meet your needs?

Comment: @AlexanderNied yes but for some reason it doesn't really center, if you try it out on a laptop resolution it will display even more the corner of the image and i can't understand why.

Comment: Do you just want to get a blurred rectangle in the center, against the background of the picture? Through the blurred rectangle, you should observe the center of the background image. So?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes, I want what's on the screenshot but displaying the image (that is on the blurred box inherited) centered instead of displaying the corner of the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost good, remove the use of `translate()` which is creating the issue and center your element using `margin:auto` instead:

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477346611705-65d1883cee1e?dpr=0.800000011920929&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=800&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.blurred-box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 550px;
  height: 670px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blurred-box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.user-login-box {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.user-login-box>* {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred-box">
  <div class="user-login-box">
    <h1>text here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```